# Formatting String in Razor with String.Format not working correctly

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-mvc, string, razor

I'm having an issue formatting a simple string in Razor, I've verified that the syntax is correct in regular C# code, but once I migrate it to my HTML page using Razor and String.Format doesn't seem to work. I'm trying to format a phone number string from `##########` to `(###)###-####` so my code for this is

```cs
@{
     string number = contact.ContactNumber;
     string formattedNumber = String.Format("({0}){1}-{2}", number.Substring(0, 3), number.Substring(3, 3), number.Substring(6, 4));
}
```

I'm trying to verify if this is correct just by doing `alert(@formattedNumber)` but it doesn't appear to be working, the alert won't even appear. However if my code is simply

```cs
@{
     string number = contact.ContactNumber;
     string formattedNumber = String.Format("{0}{1}{2}", number.Substring(0, 3), number.Substring(3, 3), number.Substring(6, 4));
}
```

Note that this one should just display the regular number, and the alert will work correctly and display `##########`
Any suggestions on why the `(###)###-####` isn't working?

Comment: You should do alert('@formattedNumber') to get the alert to work.  Note the single quotes, since this is a string.

Comment: Wow that actually worked. I think that might have just fixed my entire problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your formatting is correct, it's just the way you output it on the `alert`.

When you use `@formattedNumber` in your View this is substituted for the value in that variable. Passing that string *directly* to a JavaScript `alert` will not work in the first instance because you won't end up with a valid string to `alert`. It will work in the second instance as you will be left with a valid number passed to the `alert` function.

Imagining an example where `contact.ContactNumber` is `0123456789` the first example will give JavaScript code of

```
alert((012)345-6789);
```

which is invalid.

The second example will work because it gives JavaScript code of

```
alert(0123456789);
```

which is valid (it will alert `123456789` in this example).

As HaukurHaf points out in the comments, you actually want to output the result as a string so you need single quotes around the output in your JavaScript:

```
alert('@formattedNumber'); //note the single quotes
```

This will mean in the first example you'll get an output of:

```
alert('(012)345-6789');
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your console, my guess is you're getting a JS error causing the alert to fail. Here's your code with output along with an alternative way to do this with regexes.

```
var number = "1112223333";

//an alternative method using regexes
var regexFormat = Regex.Replace(number, @"^(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})$", "($1)$2-$3");

//The methods you provided
string formattedNumber = String.Format("{0}{1}{2}", number.Substring(0, 3), number.Substring(3, 3), number.Substring(6, 4));
string formattedNumber1 = String.Format("({0}){1}-{2}", number.Substring(0, 3), number.Substring(3, 3), number.Substring(6, 4));
```

Here's the output from this:

```
     regexFormat = (111)222-3333
 formattedNumber = 1112223333
formattedNumber1 = (111)222-3333
```

`regexFormat` and `formattedNumber1` should both provide you with what you need. I personally find the regex easier to read in this instance.

Answer (score 0):

How are you printing out the number in your HTML? Doing the following works just fine for me:

```
    @{
        string number = "0712345678";
        string formattedNumber = String.Format("({0}){1}-{2}", number.Substring(0, 3), number.Substring(3, 3), number.Substring(6, 4));
    }

    <div>@formattedNumber</div>
```

I suspect your problem isn't with the formatting of the string (the way you have it is perfectly legit) but possibly with the way you're trying to *display* the string?